# R Shiny withProgress Indicator Within Fluid Container

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I'm designing an application, and I have a withProgress() notification which is used heavily throughout. I set the bar's location with something like:

```
tags$style(
  paste0(
    ".shiny-progress-notification{",
    "  position:fixed !important;",
    "  top: calc(0.5%) !important;",
    "  left: calc(9%) !important;",
    "  font-size: 15px !important;",
    "  font-style: bold !important;",
    "  width: 500px !important;",
    "}"
  )
)
```

The issue with doing it this way is that it shows up in a different location depending on the user's monitor, as well as how much they're zoomed in, etc.

Is it possible to place the loading object within a fluid object or something of the like so that it fits into the page in a more structured way, and I don't have to define the coordinates either explicitly or with calc()?

Specifically, I'd like to put the loading bar in a `fluidRow()` at the top of the page, so that is is part of the same `mainPanel()` as everything else. I know this question is a bit broad but I'm open to any answer that keeps the loading bar in place with respect to all the fluid objects.

The raw html looks something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class = "shiny busy">
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">...</div>
    <div id="shiny-notification-panel">
      <div id="shiny-notification-f2530c977659e1a3" class="shiny-notification">
        <div class="shiny-notification-close">×</div>
        <div class="shiny-notification-content">
          <div class="shiny-notification-content-text">
            <div id="shiny-progress-f2530c977659e1a3" class="shiny-progress-notification">
              <div class="progress progress-striped active" style="">
                <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 30%;"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="progress-text">
                <span class="progress-message">Instantiating Data</span>
                <span class="progress-detail"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="shiny-notification-content-action"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So in this context I want the `shiny-progress-notification` to move in harmony with the `container-fluid`.

Comment: "depending on the user's monitor, as well as how much they're zoomed in, etc.": Just an idea. One could get these infos via Javascript and place the loading object accordingly. Would sound a bit easier than the "fluid"-approach,....Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: This sounds reasonable, though I'm far from an expert in javascript, so I'd need a fair amount of hand holding. That being said, it might also help me to understand exactly how fluid containers in html work, like how they are sized according to the window they are contained in and how that size is dynamically updated. If I knew all that I could theoretically mimic it within the tags$. But again, I don't have much intuition for this, so the more explicit you can be the better!

Comment: Ok, would i be correct that your overall goal is to have a fixed position for the box. Fluid container would be one way, but if another way brings you to this goal, you would also accept it as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, if it moves "in harmony" with the fluid containers, in that it's position and size varies with their's, that would be perfect.

Comment: I have never used Shiny or R for web development before but in order to answer this I would imagine we would need to see the Shiny code you have for the mainPanel as well. In other words, a [mcve]. As it stands, you could probably set your `mainPanel` to have the style `position: relative;` and then change your notification element from `position: fixed` to `position: absolute`. A fixed element is positioned WRT the viewport whereas an absolute element is positioned WRT to the nearest relatively positioned parent.

Comment: I tried that just now, but setting position: absolute for the loading object simply causes it to disappear.

Comment: @bk18 You would need to adjust the top and left values accordingly, and consider any z-index level as well. Again, to get help you really need to include more of the code.

Comment: @TylerH I'll update my question with some of the raw HTML if that helps.

Comment: @bk18 That helps; it's still hard to tell without the content of your site there but this is what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/cgaqzquk/1/ Let me know if that makes sense to you and if it is in line with what you're looking for or not. You can move the teal block further right or down by messing with the `top` and `left` values in the CSS.

Comment: I'm confused by your use of calc here... there's no math being done. calc(0.5%) and 0.5% should do the same thing.

Comment: I think I can answer your question, but there are several things unclear to me in your question.  Could you recreate your scenario in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the loading bar to be always on top of any fluid container then what you can do is this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div id="shiny-notification-panel"></div>
</div>
```

And apply the following styles:

```
.container-fluid{
  position: relative;
}

#shiny-notification-panel{
  position: absolute;
  // setting this tells the panel to occupy the parent's width and to always be on top
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 10px; // just sets the height
}
```

What this does is the shiny panel will always be relative to the fluid container's placement and will always be on top.